# Symfony2 & Twig, getting user variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having problems getting a user variable, in Twig.
When i'm doing a var_dump(app.user) i get the following:

```
object(App\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Employee)[1233]
  protected 'id' => int 1
  private 'group' => int 0
  protected 'fullName' => string 'Daniel Mensing' (length=14)
  protected 'username' => string 'dm' (length=2)
  protected 'usernameCanonical' => string 'dm' (length=2)
```

I've added the "fullName", which was not a part of the FOSUSerbundle.

Now, when i try to output the new variable (fullName) in twig, it tells me it does not exist(??) While the standard variables work fine(username, email..) at first i thought it was because i made fullName private, but doesnt work when protected either. Also in the vardump, they look exactly the same

I'm outputting the variables like this: `{{ app.user.username }}` or `{{ app.user.fullName }}`

Any1 can point me in the right direction? Or help explain what i'm doing wrong.
Any help is much appreciated :-) Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `getFullName` method in your entity?

Comment: use public instead of protected.

Comment: @Dezigo making entity property as public is very bad idea.

Comment: just for testing and var_dump() you can use public, anyway you should use getters and setters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Twig you can access object variables by several methods:

- Public variable. user.fullName points directly to user object variable, like if you call $object->fullName in php
- Public method. user.fullName points to `getFullName()` method of user object, like if you call $object->getFullName() in php.

So either make fullName public or add `getFullName()` method (recommended).

Answer (score 2):

`protected` means that the variabile is available just to same class AND subclasses instances, but not from anywhere else.

Provide you class with a proper `public` getter, e.g. `public function getFullname(){ return $this -> fullName; }`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add getter for `fullName` field in `App\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Employee` entity:

```
public function getFullName() {
    return $this->fullName;
}
```

Comment: That should be `getFullName()` to be a getter.